# MailApp.sendEmail not working correctly when sending email with attachments from a paid account

Tags: email, google-apps-script, email-attachments

```
function printForward() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[3];
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  var ssname = ss.getName();
  var length = ssname.length;
  var date = ssname.substring(0,length-15);
  const body = "All, <br><br>Attached is the invoice for the week of "+ date+"."+"<br><br> Thank you, <br> Elizabeth";
  
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ss.getRange('Constants!T5').getValue(),"Invoices "+date, body, date);
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody, invcdate) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName("Forward Air Invoice "+invcdate+ '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }

MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject, 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
  
  //save PDF
  const nameFile = "Forward " + invcdate + ".pdf";
  var forwardFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(ID);
  forwardFolder.createFile(blob); //HERE IS WHERE THE PDF FILE IS SAVED
```

I have the code above, it is supposed to email a pdf of a spreadsheet and then save a copy of the pdf in a folder. When I run the script, the email sends correctly and a pdf of the spreadsheet is saved to the folder. However, when the owner of the spreadsheet/script runs the script, an email sends, but an html file is attached not the pdf. So a bunch of text is sent, instead of the spreadsheet. I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attachments must be in an array.  Maybe try a different configuration as follows:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(objectOfSettings);
```

Code:

```
var mailOptions = {};
var arrayOfAttachments = [];

if (blob) {
  arrayOfAttachments.push(blob);
  mailOptions.attachments = arrayOfAttachments;
}

if (htmlbody) {
  mailOptions.htmlBody = htmlbody;
}

if (email) {
  mailOptions.to = email;
  mailOptions.subject = subject;

  MailApp.sendEmail(mailOptions);
}
```

In order to use the FROM option, you need to make some changes in your Gmail
settings.  You will need to set up an alias email, AND/OR confirm an email address that you own.
You can send an email from a non-Google email address, BUT you need to confirm that you own that email account.  That confirmation process is started in your Gmail settings under the "Accounts OR Accounts and Import" tab.  If you have a Workspace account, and you want to send an email as an alias, you will need to open the Workspace Admin Console,

https://admin.google.com/AdminHome

1. Log in as the administrator.
2. Go to Apps > Google Apps > Gmail > Advanced setting.
3. Search for "Allow per-user outbound gateways" and enable this setting.
4. Click the "Save" button to save the changes.

Go Back to the Main Admin Console
Now do the following:

click on "Users"
click on the Name of the user's account
Add an alias.
Here is a link to some Google help information.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?ctx=gmail&hl=en&authuser=0&visit_id=1-636221911743940259-3663359538&rd=1

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried your solution with three emails. Two of them work and the PDF sends correctly. One of them still sends as an HTML doc and the only difference is that the email address of this sender is a G Suite account (not an @ gmail.com address). Is this affecting the script?

Comment: If the G Suite account is using a different email sending service other than Gmail, I'm wondering if that email service is interpreting the information differently.  But that's just a wild guess.  You could try a different configuration.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to add a "from" parameter to the .sendEmail(), how would I do it in the array? I have read the documentation and I am also confused with the alias part.

Comment: The "from" option is only available to paid accounts.  A free/consumer account can't send an email as being from a different email address.  Are you trying to send "from" a consumer account?

Comment: I wrote the script using a free consumer account (personal gmail). The owner of the spreadsheet/the email I would like the send the "from", uses a GSuite account.

Comment: There is a process that needs to be done to set up and verify the alias.  See the updated answer at the bottom.  The user will need to go through the steps.  There is no way for you to automate the process with code that I know of.